# UINavigationBar hiding UIBarButtons on PushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I searched a lot and tried everything but it's not working.I am using customized UINavigationBar with array of RightBarButtonItems.Please check bellow code and images for more information -

```
-(void) makeLeftBarButtonWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
   UIImageView *imageFrame = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 2.0, 40, 30)];
   imageFrame.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];
   UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [leftButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(-9.0,0.0,60.0f, 30.0f);
   UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
  [buttonView addSubview:leftButton];
  [buttonView addSubview:imageFrame];
  barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView];
}

-(void)makeRightBarButtons
{
   UIImageView *imageFrame1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 2.0, 30, 35)];
  imageFrame1.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_notifications.png"];
  UIButton *leftButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [leftButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  leftButton1.frame = CGRectMake(-9.0,0.0,60.0f, 30.0f);
  UIView *buttonView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
 [buttonView1 addSubview:leftButton1];
 [buttonView1 addSubview:imageFrame1];
 notificationBarBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView1];


 UIImageView *imageFrame2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0, 2.0, 30, 35)];
 imageFrame2.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_note.png"];
 UIButton *leftButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 leftButton2.frame = CGRectMake(-9.0,0.0,60.0f, 30.0f);
 UIView *buttonView2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 60.0f, 30.0f)];
 [buttonView2 addSubview:leftButton2];
 [buttonView2 addSubview:imageFrame2];
 noteBarBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView2];

UIButton *leftButton3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//set this name on view
[leftButton3 setTitle:@"Start Class" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(startStopClassBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
leftButton3.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 2.0,150.0f, 30.0f);
UIView *buttonView3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 7, 150.0f, 30.0f)];
[buttonView3 addSubview:leftButton3];
startClassBarBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView3];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        if ([self.navigationController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealGesture:)] && [self.navigationController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealToggle:)]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealGesture:)];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer];

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,44)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
        self.title =@"First";

       customizeUI  =[[CustomizeUI alloc]init];
        [customizeUI makeLeftBarButtonWithTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
       // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customizeUI.barButtonItem;
    }
customizeUI.delegate =self;

[customizeUI makeRightBarButtons];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: customizeUI.barButtonItem,customizeUI.notificationBarBtnItem,customizeUI.noteBarBtnItem,customizeUI.startClassBarBtnItem,nil];

//[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 1024, 22)];
statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
// [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:statusBarView];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

[image]

[image]

I put this code on both view controllers but still it's not working. When I run a code on first view controller all buttons are showing properly but when I call push navigation and move on next view controller it's not showing buttons and even back button is also not working and I have added one back button on second view controller using that back button when I navigate to first view controller it's showing nothing on header without color. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: hide your default navigationbar on viewdidload

Comment: Welcome , i put my comment as answer, it may help to others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your default navigation is coming over to your navigation, so your controls that you have added in the navigation bar will be hidden. As per comment to resolve you need to hide your default navigation bar.